# How to create Contained Database in sql server 2102

Tags: sql-server

plz give me detail of Contained Database = true in Sql Server 2012
 **how to use and why ?**

Answer (score 0):

How to [Migrate to a Partially Contained Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929139.aspx):

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Accounting] SET CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL
GO
```

What are [Contained Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2012:

> A contained database is a database that is isolated from other
>   databases and from the instance of SQL Server that hosts the database.
>   SQL Server 2012 helps user to isolate their database from the instance
>   in 4 ways.
>
> - Much of the metadata that describes a database is maintained in the database. (In addition to, or instead of, maintaining metadata in
>     the master database.)
> - All metadata are defined using the same collation.
> - User authentication can be performed by the database, reducing the databases dependency on the logins of the instance of SQL Server.
> - The SQL Server environment (DMV's, XEvents, etc.) reports and can act upon containment information.